# Stockholm public transport ticket prices for young people

Tags: transportation, sweden, price, stockholm

It seems that a reduced price for transportation tickets within Stockholm is available for young people up to the age of 20 years. But I can't find out whether it is up to 20 (including 20) or if you have to be younger than that (so up to and including 19, but not including those aged twenty).

I am 20 and I want to buy a travel card for 72 hours but I don't know whether or not I can buy the ticket for reduced price.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Terms and Conditions of the Stockholm public transport system](https://sl.se/globalassets/villkor/villkor-eng.html):

> Children and young people may travel at a discounted price from and including when they turn 6 until the day they reach the age of 20.

So it looks like you'll have to pay full price.

Comment: Students are also eligable for reduced prices.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder: true, but they need a "valid student ID card with the SL logo." so it seems to apply only for students of universities in Stockholm, and I don't think they will be looking for information here.

Answer (score -2):

The reduced price for tickets is only for teenagers (up to 19, that is). So unfortunately you cannot travel with those. But if you are a student and are carrying some student ID (even if you live abroad), I believe you can get tickets within the same price range as the reduced ones!

Comment: The student ticket is only available for 30 or 90 days and alone therefore not useful in this case. It is also only available to students from designated Swedish schools and not at all to foreign students visiting Stockholm.